# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: posts

Tags: python, flask

When I try to run my Flask App, I get the following message: [This is BOTH after I tried commenting and uncommenting out the db.create_all() command seen further below]

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such 
table: posts
```

Here is my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + 
os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
app.config.update(dict(
SECRET_KEY="powerful secretkey",
WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY="a csrf secret key"
))

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

#db.create_all()
```

Here is my models.py:

```
from flask_mongoengine.wtf import model_form
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, EmailField, 
ReferenceField, IntField, DateTimeField, \
BooleanField, DictField, ListField, EmbeddedDocument, \
EmbeddedDocumentListField, FloatField, FileField
from datetime import datetime 
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, 
check_password_hash
from flask import request
from hashlib import md5
from app import db
#from app import mongo 


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref = 'author', lazy='dynamic')


class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    body = db.column(db.Text)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, 
    default=datetime.utcnow)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Here is my views.py:

```
import bcrypt
#import magic
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, flash, redirect, 
session, url_for, g, jsonify, make_response
from werkzeug.datastructures import CombinedMultiDict
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from app import app
from app import db

from models import User, Post 
from forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, ForgotForm, ProfileForm, 
ResetPassword, InviteForm, PostForm
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, 
login_required, LoginManager
import os
from flask_babel import Babel, lazy_gettext
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, IMAGES, configure_uploads
from flask_avatar import Avatar
from momentjs import momentjs
from flask_mail import Mail

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#@app.route('/index/<int:page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    post = Post(body=form.body.data, author = 
    current_user._get_current_object())
    db.session.add(post)
    return redirect(url_for('frontpage'))
posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).all() 
return render_template('frontpage.html', form=form, posts=posts)
```

I believe the error is that despite having defined the model, I haven't actually created the table in the database that matches the model ..? When I try to do the following in the terminal:

```
python models.py shell
```

I get the following message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'users' is already defined for 
this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine 
options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

Its my understanding that if the above command worked successfully, Id be able to run the following commands in the terminal:

```
from models import db
db.create_all()
```

and that would create the table posts i'm trying to make ...

any help would be greatly appreciated. I think i'm missing something here ...

Comment: I have not worked on Flask much. But I cannot see where have you defined the engine or session. Without that configuration I don't think you would be able to communicate to the db

Comment: i don't see any link between the file app.py and models.py/view.py, how are you running the app ?